# Runs in both Access 2010 and SQL Server but gives different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Hi I have a the query below that runs in both access 2010 and SQL Server 2012. The problem is that the answers for the percentage are not the same. In SQL Server I get 0 % for each chapter in SQL Server.

```
SELECT 
TOP 5 1 AS Type, C.Chapname AS Chapter, Z.ChapPct AS Percentage
FROM 
(SELECT 
X.Chapter, (count(X.Chapter)/(select count(*) 
FROM 
( SELECT 
LEFT(Stats.Diag,1) as Chapter 
FROM
Stats
) X 
))*100 AS ChapPct 
FROM 
(SELECT 
LEFT(Stats.Diag,1) as Chapter 
FROM 
Stats 
)  AS X 
GROUP BY 
X.Chapter)  AS Z 
INNER JOIN 
Chapter_tbl AS C ON Z.Chapter = C.Chapter
ORDER BY 
Z.ChapPct DESC;
```

The output is:

```
Type |  Chapter           | pecentage
-------------------------------------
1    |  Urological    | 0
1    |  Endocrine     | 0
1    |  Psychological | 0
1    |  Eye           | 0
1    |  Digestive     | 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this make a difference?

```
SELECT 
TOP 5 1 AS Type, C.Chapname AS Chapter, Z.ChapPct AS Percentage
FROM 
(SELECT 
X.Chapter, (count(X.Chapter) * 1.000 /(select count(*) * 1.000
FROM 
( SELECT 
LEFT(Stats.Diag,1) as Chapter 
FROM
Stats
) X 
))*100 AS ChapPct 
FROM 
(SELECT 
LEFT(Stats.Diag,1) as Chapter 
FROM 
Stats 
)  AS X 
GROUP BY 
X.Chapter)  AS Z 
INNER JOIN 
Chapter_tbl AS C ON Z.Chapter = C.Chapter
ORDER BY 
Z.ChapPct DESC;
```

I think you're losing the precision because the division is only returning the whole number portion of the operation.  * 1.000 should force the precision to a greater granularity.

Comment: Hi VBlades yes * 1.000 made a difference. It was losing precision. thanks